# How do I use named ranges in LibreOffice?

Tags: libreoffice

I'm guessing this is a bug but I thought I'd ask anyway. I'm using `LibreOffice` 4.2.4.2 on `Debian Wheezy` and have created some named ranges, one of which is `Dates`, another is `Amounts`.

When I type `SUM(Amounts)` into a cell, I get the sum of the `Date` values, and when I look at the cell after I've hit `enter`, the cell content reads `SUM(Dates)`. `Amounts` and `Dates` **do not** point to the same range.

Other than not using ranges (which isn't a pleasant option in LibreOffice unfortunately) is there some workaround for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This bug seemed to appear after I had used the recover option following a force-quit by `LibreOffice`. Avoiding autorecover and saving my work pedantically seems to have avoided this particular problem for now..